# How to select some characters in value of a column and create a new column with this value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv as below:

```
Date        File Name        
11/05/2018  CFL200_ABCD
11/06/2018  CFL203_DFSA
```

I would like to create a new column with values are characters before "_" in the File Name column

```
Date        File Name        ID
11/05/2018  CFL200_ABCD      CFL200
11/06/2018  CFL203_DFSA      CFL203
```

How could I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use first [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split string into sub-string and then get item through index

```
df["ID"] = df["File Name"].str.split('_').str[0]
df
         Date    File Name      ID
0  11/05/2018  CFL200_ABCD  CFL200
1  11/06/2018  CFL203_DFSA  CFL203
```